# Netbeans not opening in Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, netbeans

Netbeans not opening in Ubuntu when opened from terminal, The following error is displayed.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/nio/file/InvalidPathException
at org.openide.filesystems.FileUtil.normalizeFileImpl(Unknown Source)
at org.openide.filesystems.FileUtil.normalizeFile(Unknown Source)
at org.netbeans.core.startup.TopLogging.printSystemInfo(Unknown Source)
at org.netbeans.core.startup.TopLogging.initialize(Unknown Source)
at org.netbeans.core.startup.TopLogging.initialize(Unknown Source)
at org.netbeans.core.startup.CLIOptions.initialize(Unknown Source)
at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.start(Unknown Source)
at org.netbeans.core.startup.TopThreadGroup.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
... 9 more
```

pls help me ...

Comment: What's the Netbeans Version

Comment: Try the latest version as 7.0.1 has some bugs and install latest jdk either 1.7.x or 1.8.x

Answer (score 0):

- Netbeans did not open on the command because the shell does not know the path to your binary file.
- If binary files are located in /usr/bin (the default path to application's binary files) they will open right away